# Can one ask "he went where" instead of "where did he go"?

Tags: questions

I'm not sure but it's quite obvious that I've heard and read of such questions occasionally. Is this acceptable in terms of grammatical writing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a regular statement, normally "Where did he go?" would be used.

However your other phrase could be used in spoken language to show disbelief or amazement. "where" would be emphasized.

> He went **where**?